# Ecto validate_required on belongs_to when Struct or nil passed

Tags: elixir, belongs-to, ecto

What is the right way to perform validation on Struct with association passed explicitly?

```
def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
  model
  |> cast(params, [:name])
  |> validate_required([:make, :name])
  |> update_change(:name, &String.downcase/1)
  |> unique_constraint(:name, name: :models_name_make_id_index)
end
```

How I'm going to use it:

```
changeset(%Model{make: make}, %{....})
```

Where make can be nil. And I want proper error message instead of:

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function nil.id/0 is undefined or private
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validations are mainly intended for processing user input, not ensuring data consistency. In case you're creating data programatically, validations are not the right tool to guard against programmer errors (in case someone forgot about adding the association) - database constraints are.

When processing user input for associations, functions like `cast_assoc/3` and `cast_embed/3` accept the `required: true` option to enforce the association's presence.

It might be a good idea to create a function that does the right thing and adds the association, instead of scattering that logic over the controllers (or other places calling the changeset function).

Comment: Ok, this is what I thought and finally ended up with function that pattern matches provided assoc :( Though would be nice to kinda lock it forever in one place.

Comment: @IvanYouroff could you provide that function here?

Comment: It evolved a bit already. Initially it was just a pattern-matching on the result of previous operation. So to make life simpler I created a tiny library implementing Result and Option monadic type. It sounds fancy, but in fact it's just tuple with macro ok(value) is converted to {:ok, value} and error(e) to {:error, e} which matches perfectly most of Erlang/Elixir libs. Here's the library: https://github.com/youroff/monex, here's the gist, how I used it in this case: https://gist.github.com/youroff/8812191758e8df0d69f7d8c94b650b33